# Yoga (proper-case) or yoga (lowercase)?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

I've seen it written in both ways.  I'm tempted to use the proper case, because I was under the impression that it is also a form/name of religion.  What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a religion in and of itself.  Elements of [yoga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga) are found in Hinduism, Buddhism, and Jainism. Given that, I would say lowercase.

Comment: That Wikipedia article uses both lowercase and propercase.

Comment: My point was more that it's not a formal religion.  And as such, I wouldn't use it the proper case.

Comment: It's a good point.  Dictionaries also state that it is a noun and not a proper noun.  Perhaps my question should be, when should I use capitalization?  Such as God and god from the Christian perspective.  Perhaps I should use yoga for the exercise and Yoga for the elements found in religions.

Answer (score 1):

In *[Autobiography of a Yogi](http://www.ananda.org/inspiration/books/ay/)* (Paramhansa Yogananda's chronicles on Yogis, yoga, and related topics), the word *yoga* is used with a lower case *y*. But where it clearly is part of a noun, such as in *[Kriya Yoga](http://www.ananda.org/inspiration/books/ay/)*, the uppercase is used.

Comment: Good point.  Specific forms should definitely be capitalized. I.E., Ashtanga, Bikram, etc.