# Yoga terms in English and the capitalization thereof

Tags: capitalization, style-manuals

I'm editing a manuscript in English that contains numerous yoga terms for poses, concepts etc. These are generally derived from Sanskrit, if not actual Sanskrit transliterations. My publisher requires Chicago Style, however a search yields nothing helpful with regard to capitalization of these terms. For instance, is the word yoga itself to be capitalized? In some instances but not all? What about yoga/yoga concepts, like *Dharana*? Capitalized? Always? I'm in a pickle.

Comment: What's a "ms."?

Comment: Related question :(http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41709/yoga-proper-case-or-yoga-lowercase)

Comment: @Hugo I wondered about that too! M.S. would be Master of Science, but maybe "ms." means a master's degree in any field. A master's degree sometimes requires completion of a thesis, so I guess it is a Master's  thesis written in English, but not in the field of English (Literature), because the focus is yoga. It would interesting to learn the actual facts though!

Comment: @FeralOink (and Hugo): "ms." stands for "manuscript". This was a pretty common abbreviation, at least a few decades ago (consider e.g. Poe's [MS. Found in a Bottle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS._Found_in_a_Bottle)).

Comment: Thank you @ShreevatsaR I wasn't thinking of it in the right context. (Or not thinking at all...) Now that you give the answer, it seems well, obvious <slight chagrin>!

Answer (score 4):

You mention that your publisher requires Chicago Style citations. The Chicago Manual of Style, **[Chapter 7: Italics and Capitalization of Foreign Words](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch07/ch07_toc.html)** (see sections 7.49 through 7.51 specifically) gives some guidance. There are also several existing questions **[here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9279/how-should-foreign-words-with-foreign-characters-be-written-in-english-text)** and **[particularly here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/fait-accompli-to-italicize-or-not-to-italicize)** that are related, and may help.

Italicizing seems standard practice. However, capitalizing and italicizing every yoga-related term will be awkward. Based on my own quick review of this site, and what I could view without a full  subscription to the Chicago Manual of Style, plus my own experience with biological taxonomy terms, I would do this:

- Italicize all Sanskrit words that are yoga related and have not passed into common English usage.
- Italicize AND capitalize Sanskrit yoga concepts, to delineate the difference and significance from poses.

Answer (score 0):

See related [Should capitalization be preserved in loanwords?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15241/should-capitalization-be-preserved-in-loanwords)

I would only capitalise them if not doing so is likely to cause offence, ie. if the word is the name of a deity. Even then, only if yoga people are the type to get violent with rage about that sort of thing ;-)